# Java OSX Why does the JDK need to be installed for my script to run properly?

Tags: java, macos

I manually created a jar file and it's manifest file through OSX's Terminal.  The jar requires the Terminal switch `-XstartOnFirstThread` in order to run properly on OSX.  It worked fine on my mac, but when I tried running it on someone else's mac, the switch wasn't working.

After checking java versions. I noticed that I was running Java version "1.7.0_45" while the computer in question was running only Java version 1.6.......

Downloading and running the latest JRE didn't change this version, but downloading the latest JDK did the trick and now the switch works.

My question is, why would someone need the development kit installed in order to run a jar that I created?  That doesn't seem practical.  Or am I incorrect in this assumption and installing the JDK included updates that could have been installed without installing the entire JDK?

Sorry if this sounds muddled, I'm just making my way around understanding which kits do what so please be as clear as possible in explaining this.  Thanks in advance,